# List of Strings obtained by replacing each character in a String by all other alphabet characters

Tags: string, haskell, replace, char

I want a function that replaces a letter in a String with every other letter form the alphabet.
Example:

```
f :: String -> [String]
f = ...

ghci> f "foo"
["aoo","boo,"coo","doo","eoo","goo","hoo"..."fao",fbo","fco","fdo",...."foa","fob","foc","fod"...]
```

I currently got:

```
alphabet :: [Char]
alphabet = ['a'..'z']

replaced1 :: String -> [String]
replaced1 [] = []
replaced1 (x:xs) = (alphabet++xs) : map (x:) (replaced1 xs)
```

Of course this doesnt work because it adds the whole alphabet but I don't know how to take only one char from the alphabet.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: *I want a function that replaces a letter in a String.* You're gonna have to be more specific than that.

Comment: One thing you could do to improve this question is to give some sample inputs and the corresponding outputs you expect.

Comment: You are right. I hope this example helps.

Comment: No its not about a specific letter. The function should replace every single letter from a String with every other letter besides the one thats already at the position. So for "ab" it should be ['b'..'z'] and for the b ['a','c'..'z']. The input is unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the argument of your function matches the pattern `(x:xs)`; for the sake of brevity, I won't discuss the base case.

1. Use a list comprehension to generate a list of Strings in which `x` is replaced by all other letters in your alphabet:

   ```
   [ c:xs | c <- alphabet, c /= x ]
   ```

   The generator draws a character `c` from the alphabet, but the predicate forbids `c` to be the same as `x`.
2. Apply your function recursively to the tail of the String argument, `xs`:

   ```
   f xs
   ```
3. Prepend character `x` to each String in the list of Strings obtained in 2.:

   ```
   map (x:) (f xs)
   ```
4. Append the result of 3. to that of 1.:

   ```
   [ c:xs | c <- alphabet, c /= x ] ++ map (x:) (f xs)
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
alphabet :: String
alphabet = ['a'..'z']

f :: String -> [String]
f     [] = []
f (x:xs) = [ c:xs | c <- alphabet, c /= x ] ++ map (x:) (f xs)
```

Test:

```
ghci> f "foo"  
["aoo","boo","coo","doo","eoo","goo","hoo","ioo","joo","koo","loo","moo","noo",
"ooo","poo","qoo","roo","soo","too","uoo","voo","woo","xoo","yoo","zoo","fao",
"fbo","fco","fdo","feo","ffo","fgo","fho","fio","fjo","fko","flo","fmo","fno",
"fpo","fqo","fro","fso","fto","fuo","fvo","fwo","fxo","fyo","fzo","foa","fob",
"foc","fod","foe","fof","fog","foh","foi","foj","fok","fol","fom","fon","fop",
"foq","for","fos","fot","fou","fov","fow","fox","foy","foz"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly fine. The explanation is really helpful to someone thats comming from an imperative langueage like me.

Comment: I probably should open another question but since i use this code here i do it as a comment. I want to insert every letter to the string. Ex: f "st" -> ["ast","bst",...,"sat","sbt",...,"sta","stb",...]
I used the code above so it's: f (x:xs) = [c:x:xs | c <- alphabet] ++ map (x:) (f xs)
But it obviously doesnt add the letters to the end.