# Function that replaces all characters in a string with all alphabetical characters Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

Giving a string, I need a function that returns a list of strings formed by replacing each character from the original string with every small letter in the alphabet. For example `"car"` -> `["aar","bar","dar",....,"cbr","ccr",...]`.
I tried this:

```
replaced1 :: String -> [String]
replaced1 [] = []
replaced1 (x:xs) = [h ['a'..'z'] : map (x:) (replaced1 xs)
         where h[] = []
               h c= head c  (h(tail c))
```

but it gives my a parse error at `where`. I'm just learning Haskell, so I am not used with this kind of errors. How can I solve this  ?

Comment: in the last equation for `replaced1` you have a `[` but no `]`, that's why it gives you the parse error.

Comment: thanks, but now I still get a parse error at input "=" on  the last row

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces? Try using only spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of Strings obtained by replacing each character in a String by all other alphabet characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949520/list-of-strings-obtained-by-replacing-each-character-in-a-string-by-all-other-al)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. First, it looks like you're thinking of using a list comprehension with `[h ['a'..'z']...` You're trying to replace the first character of the string with each character in the series `['a' .. 'z']`. The syntax for that is `[h c | c <- ['a'..'z']]`. Ask in the comments (or revise your post) if you need clarification or if this wasn't what you had in mind.

Second, the type of `h` should be `Char -> String`. It takes the character to replace, and then uses the rest of the input to `replaced1` (i.e. `xs`).

Third, for combining lists use `(++)` not `:`. The type of `map (x:) (replaced1 xs)` is `[String]`, but so is the type of what you're adding it to.

Here's the fixed version, with a bit left for you to fill in.

```
replaced1 :: String -> [String]
replaced1 [] = []
replaced1 (x:xs) = [h c | c <- ['a'..'z']] ++ map (x:) (replaced1 xs)
         where h :: Char -> String
               h c = {- left as exercise -}
```